# how to find $A^{-1}$ in a matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse

I have been given this matrix

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 9 & 4 \\ 5 & 6 & 8 \\ 1 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

and I have to find $A^{-1}$, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: 30 days a member, 8 questions asked. Common, learn how to properly write mathematics in this site.

Comment: Take a look at [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to type mathematics correctly on this site using $\LaTeX$ and MathJax.  As for the content of your question, "$1$" is not usually interpreted as a $3\times 3$ matrix and subtractions involving $A$ would only make sense between two $3\times 3$ matrices.  Do you mean for $1$ to be the $3\times 3$ identity matrix perhaps instead?  Or are you wanting to find the multiplicative inverse of the matrix?

Comment: is there a tutorial or something to learn how to do it?

Comment: @JMoravitz given the edit it appears he's asking for the inverse.

Comment: @eyeballfrog the edit wasn't done by the OP and the original way the question was asked does not make it clear which of the two was intended (*if even one of those two is the intended, it could still be something else entirely*).  It should be the OP who should clarify what the problem is meant to ask, not us making assumptions.

Comment: yes, the edit is correct. thank you projectilemotion for fixing it.

Comment: @anon420 Anyways, this should give you everything you need https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Finding_the_inverse_of_a_matrix

Comment: @anon420 You're welcome. Which way have you learnt to find the inverse of $3\times 3$ matrices?

Comment: @anon420 apparently the question is in the title and you have nothing else to say...

Answer (score 4):

One of the first methods commonly taught is to row reduce $\left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}3&9&4&1&0&0\\5&6&8&0&1&0\\1&0&2&0&0&1\end{array}\right]$ and put this into reduced row echelon form

Assuming the inverse actually exists where initially we begin with $[A\mid I]$ the result of the row reduction will be $[I\mid A^{-1}]$.  If it is impossible to row reduce in such a way that the left-half of the augmented matrix reduces to the identity then the matrix is not invertible.

Other methods exist as well and can be found on the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Methods_of_matrix_inversion).

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @JMoravitz, one strategy is to use elementary operations to reduce the  augmented matrix 
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{c|c} \mathbf{A} & \mathbf{I} \end{array} \right] \to \left[ \begin{array}{c|c} \mathbf{I} & \mathbf{A}^{-1} \end{array} \right].
$$

1. Swap the first and third rows, this makes the top row look more like the target identity matrix.
   2  Row 2: subtract 5 $\times$ row 1. Row 3: subtract 3 $\times$ row 1.
2. Normalize rows 2 and 3.
3. Subtract row 2 from row 3.
4. Normalize row 3.
5. Row 1: subtract 2 $\times$ row  3. Row 2: add one third of row  3.

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
 3 & 9 & 4 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 5 & 6 & 8 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\overset{1}{\longrightarrow}
%
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 5 & 6 & 8 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 3 & 9 & 4 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\overset{2}{\longrightarrow}
%
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 6 & -2 & 0 & 1 & -5 \\
 0 & 9 & -2 & 1 & 0 & -3 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\overset{3}{\longrightarrow}
%
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & -\frac{5}{6} \\
 0 & 1 & -\frac{2}{9} & \frac{1}{9} & 0 & -\frac{1}{3} \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\overset{4}{\longrightarrow}
%
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & -\frac{5}{6} \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{9} & \frac{1}{9} & -\frac{1}{6} &
   \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\overset{5}{\longrightarrow}
%
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & -\frac{5}{6} \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & -\frac{3}{2} & \frac{9}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\overset{6}{\longrightarrow}
%
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
 1 & 0 & 0 & -2 & 3 & -8 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3} \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & -\frac{3}{2} & \frac{9}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Harvest the matrix inverse
$$
  \mathbf{A}^{-1} =
\frac{1}{6}
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
 -12 & 18 & -48 \\
 2 & -2 & 4 \\
 6 & -9 & 27 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

You should verify that $\mathbf{A} \, \mathbf{A}^{-1}= \mathbf{A}^{-1}\, \mathbf{A}=\mathbf{I}_{3}.$